# Как поменять алгоритм шифрование в AsymmetricAlgorithm

Tags: c#, .net, криптография

Задача уйти от ошибки в проверки подписи объекта SignedXml. Проблема в том, что после последних обновлений windows, они отключили поддержку алгоритма

> http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1

Но проблема в том, что он является дефолтным для 
`X509Certificate2.PrivateKey`

И этот

```
   public AsymmetricAlgorithm PrivateKey { get; set; }
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Получает объект System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.PublicKey,
    //     связанный с сертификатом.
    //
    // Возвращает:
    //     Объект System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.PublicKey.
    //
    // Исключения:
    //   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
    //     Значение ключа не является значением RSA или DSA, или ключ не читается.
```

По дефолту имеет именно алгоритм rsa-sha1. И я не знаю как его подменить(Наследовать все классы из задачи включая SignedXml-кажется плохим решением)? Буду рад любой информации по вопросу! На сайте msdn мне ответили, что нужно изначально иметь сертификаты с другим алгоритмом [Вопрос на MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/8eb7be92-ff6e-4e31-a290-6b043e8b5f28/-systemsecuritycryptographyxmlsignedxml?forum=programminglanguageru).
 А вот на форуме КриптоПро, что алгоритм можно использовать другой.[Вопрос на форуме КриптоПро](https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=11200&p=2).

Comment: Оно? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733772(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @andreycha Да именно оно. Оформите, пожалуйста ваш комментарий, как ответ. Ввиду недавних обновлений windows, это будет актуальный вопрос!

Comment: Сделал. Если будут замечания по переводу -- подскажите, поправлю.

Comment: А что вам мешает просто взять сертификат с поддерживаемым алгоритмом?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Огромное число  клиентов  сертификаты которых мне не изменить и большое число кода, где используются сертификаты X509.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по документации MSDN, можно. Для этого надо:

1. Создать новый класс и отнаследовать его от `X509AsymmetricSecurityKey`.
2. Переопределить свойство `KeySize`. Это свойство возвращает размер ключа сертификата (пары публичный/приватный ключ)
3. Переопределить метод `DecryptKey`. Этот метод вызывается WCF, чтобы расшифровать симметричный ключ с помощью приватного ключа сертификата.
4. Переопределить метод `GetAsymmetricAlgorithm`. Этот метод вызывается WCF и возвращает экземпляр класса `AsymmetricAlgorithm`, представляющего собой криптопровайдер для приватного или публичного ключа сертификата, в зависимости от переданного параметра.
5. Опционально: переопределить метод `GetHashAlgorithmForSignature`. Переопределите этот метод, если вам нужно использовать другую реализацию `HashAlgorithm`.
6. Переопределите метод `GetSignatureFormatter`. Этот метод возвращает экземпляр класса `AsymmetricSignatureFormatter`, связанный с приватным ключом экземпляра.
7. Переопределите метод `IsSupportedAlgorithm`. Этот метод используется для проверки поддержки криптографического алгоритма данной реализацией ключа.

Также потребуется:

1. Создать наследника `X509SecurityToken`, использующего кастомный ключ.
2. Создать наследника `SecurityTokenProvider`, возвращающего кастомный токен из п.1.
3. Создать наследника `ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager`, если ключ нужен на стороне клиента.
4. Создать наследника `ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager`, если ключ нужен на стороне сервера.

---

Подробнее в статье [Изменение поставщика служб шифрования для закрытого ключа сертификата X.509](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/ms733772(v=vs.110).aspx) на MSDN.

Comment: Русская версия тут подходит https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/ms733772(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @YuryBakharev да, действительно. Днем MSDN почему-то не захотел показывать перевод по ссылке ru-ru. Подправил ссылку в ответе, спасибо.